# SGML replace tags and write to new and different file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sgml

I have a very long SGML file which I need to convert to a another syntax, but for some reason my code don't work, when I get the output it is the exactly the same document, the code is as following:

```
#!usr/bin/env ruby 

def replaceStrings(toChange)

  ##Remove Title tags and replace with the correct 
  toChange.gsub(/<title>/) { "====="  }
  toChange.gsub(/<\/title>/) { "====="  }

  ##Image
  toChange.gsub(/<graphic fileref="/) { "{{"  }
  toChange.gsub(/<\/graphic>/) { "|}}"  }
  toChange.gsub(/;" scale="60">/) { ""  }

  ##Paragraphs
  toChange.gsub(/<para>/) { ""  }
  toChange.gsub(/<\/para>/) { ""  }

  puts toChange

end

fileInput = ARGV[0]
fileOutput = ARGV[1]

document = File.readlines(fileInput)
puts fileInput
puts fileOutput
document.each { |e|  replaceStrings(e)}

File.new(fileOutput, 'w')
File.open(fileOutput, 'w'){
  |f| f.write(document)
}
```

As far as I can tell I do call the replaceString method, but am I missing something or doing some thing wrong?

NOTE: I am pretty new at Ruby

Comment: I +1's seph's answer, but: you're treating a structured file like plain text--while this may work exactly as you intend, IMO an actual transformation would be more reliable and precise. For really simple SGML files it may not matter--just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use gsub!

Also, no need to use the block form:

```
toChange.gsub!(/<title>/, "=====")
```

Also, I don't think you need File new:

```
File.open(fileOutput, 'w') do |f|
  f.write(document)
end
```